# Permanently post some form data on another page

Tags: php, html, forms

The question looks quite similar, however it's not been answered anywhere. What I want is I'm designing a website with login option. There is a particular page named "announcements.php" where I want site visitors to be able to see announcements made by admin. So, In order to do so I have made a page which only admin can access and add an announcement ("newbroadcast.php"). The page contains a form where admin can write an announcement and submit it. However that announcement should be accessible to all the users which visit announcements.php

**Code (newbroadcast.php)**

```
<div class="newbroad">
    <img src="content/images/broadcast.png" align="center" width="160px" height="160px">
    <form method="post" action="announcements.php">
        <strong>BROADCAST :&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
        <input type="text" name="broadd" placeholder="Write your new announcement here...">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">&#160;&#160;<input type="reset" name="reset">
    </form>
</div>
```

**Code (announcements.php)**

```
<div class="markcontent">
    <center><h1 class="whiteboard">CDC DEPARTMENT WHITEBOARD</h1></center>
    <hr>
    <?php
        $mynewbroad=$_POST["broadd"];
    ?>
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="down" scrollamount="2" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
        <center>
        <?php
            echo $mynewbroad;
        ?>
        </center>
    </marquee>
```

**What is actually happening?**

Everything works fine, however when admin writes a new announcement or broadcast it gets posted on the page ("announcements.php"), where I actually want to post it. However that is not permanent. Whenever I open the page itself it shows an error => Undefined index: broadd

Is their any way to permanently show the broadcasts made by admin? What is the possible solution to this error?

Comment: This question has been answered often before... the problem is that $_POST['broadd'] is not set. And as @MawiaHL says, you need to store the data somewhere and then fetch it again upon loading the page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSTing data to a PHP page does not automatically "store" the information you are posting to it. It merely sends the data from `newbroadcast.php` to the `announcements.php`, and `announcements.php` can do what it is programmed to do with the data. In your case, `announcements.php` is displaying the data - but not storing it for future.

To store the data for future, you must save it somewhere on the server and re-factor `announcements.php` to check on the server for such data, and (if such data is found) display all the announcements via some sort of loop.

So how to store the announcements?

You can use PHP commands such as `fwrite` or `file_put_contents` to save the announcements into a specific folder, and then write a loop to read all the file in that folder and spit them out onto the page.

But the better way is to use a database.

References:

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-insert-query.php

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpQts3ezPVg

Comment: Thank you so much!